# Can't return a List using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a viewmodel that will combine the firstname and lastname

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public string emp_id { get; set; }
    public string fullname{ get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeDTO> EmployeeDTOMap(List<employeeinfo> entities)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
            cfg.CreateMap<employeeinfo, EmployeeDTO>()
                .ForMember(d => d.emp_id, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.emp_id))
                .ForMember(d => d.fullname,
                    o => o.MapFrom(src => string.Format("{0} {1}", src.firstname, src.lastname)))
                .ForAllOtherMembers(o => o.MapAtRuntime());
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var dest = mapper.Map(mapper.Map(entities, typeof(List<employeeinfo>)), new List<EmployeeDTO>());
        return dest;
    }

}
```

but the only issue is the return value is null eventhough I pass 2 entities EmployeeDTOMap().

Comment: Is there any reason, you are mapping twice? You can change the code to `mapper.Map<List<EmployeeDTO>>(entities)` which map the entities `List<employeeinfo>` to `List<EmployeeDTO>`.

Comment: the outer mapper.map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need an automapper?

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public string emp_id { get; set; }
    public string fullname { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeDTO> EmployeeDTOMap(List<employeeinfo> entities)
    {
        return entities.Select(o => new EmployeeDTO
        {
            emp_id = o.emp_id,
            fullname = string.Format("{0} {1}", o.firstname, o.lastname)
        }).ToList();
    }

}
```